# PySpark split in (Key, Array[Values]) best practice

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am fairly new to Spark and I am interested to learn what is best practice right from the beginning, but could not find similar queries so far. I got some (a lot) of data consisting of lines as such :

```
['this is some key; followed, by, some, values',
'this is some other key; followed, by, some, , other, values']
```

I would like to split these lines, such I got a `(key,value)` pair looking like this:

```
(this is some key, [followed, by, some, values])
(this is some other key, [followed, by, some, other, values])
```

What would the most efficient or prettiest way to do this?
I tried using a UDF:

```
def key_value_pair(line):
    
    if not line:
        return
    split_line = line.split(';')
    k, v = split_line[0], split_line[1]
    return (k, [v])
```

coupled with

```
rdd.map(lambda x: key_value_pair(x))
```

giving me the correct result, but I read that one should avoid using UDF in Spark.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an UDF. You are using an RDD with a map and lambda function. UDFs are for dataframes for pyspark.

That is to say, fine what you have.